# Can't Build Gambit Game Theory Extension

Tags: python, game-theory

I have installed the dependencies for the [Gambit](http://www.gambit-project.org/gambit13/pyapi.html) python interface, but am getting a config.h error (see below) when attempting to build the gambit library. I am running Yosemite 10.10.13 and using Terminal on a MacBook Air (2014).

Here is the error message:

```
172-16-226-146:python hsl306$ python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
skipping 'gambit/lib/libgambit.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'gambit.lib.libgambit' extension
/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -pipe -Os -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I../.. -I.. -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c gambit/lib/libgambit.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/gambit/lib/libgambit.o
In file included from gambit/lib/libgambit.cpp:247:
../libgambit/libgambit.h:30:11: fatal error: 'config.h' file not found
 #include <config.h>
          ^
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just managed to make the Gambit library to work in my command line.

There are many steps and mistakes you may encounter in the installation:

1. As @theycallhimtom said, the issue is that you need to build Gambit before you can build the python interface. Follow the instructions in the link to build Gambit first.
2. While building, you may encounter the error that after you clone Gambit to your local environment from Github, and go into the directory, you can't run ./configure.
3. You'll have to install the 3 tools/dependency they require to install: autoconf, automake, and libtool. All these can be installed using brew install ... (brew install autoconf, brew install automake, and brew install libtool)
4. After the installation you should try to run aclocal. If it doesn't work, you need to create an m4 directory using mkdir m4 in the Gambit directory you cloned (make sure m4 is installed, if not install it either using brew install m4 or cloning it from Github)
5. When you installed the m4 directory, try to run libtoolize. If it works, fine. In case it doesn't, simply add 'g' to libtoolize to make it glibtoolize and it will work (programming sometimes is like magic)
6. After that, automake and autoconf should work fine, if properly installed.
7. Try running ./configure and sudo make install to build Gambit into your system. You should have no problem here.
8. Get into the Python dir using cd src/python, and then try running python setup.py build.
9. At this point, you'll probably get an error saying gcc couldn't compile, or something like that. Don't panic. Simply open the file where the error is found (should be a c++ file), and manually correct these errors. Should be around 20 errors. All you need to do is add space to right-angled brackets (at least that's what I did)
10. Run sudo python setup.py install, and you should be finally able to install Gambit library into Python.
11. Don't follow their documentation on this [page](http://www.gambit-project.org/gambit13/pyapi.html#gambit.new_tree). It's outdated and doesn't work. Use their [Github page](https://github.com/gambitproject/gambit/blob/master/doc/pyapi.rst#id1) instead.

That's how I could get Gambit library working for me in Python, hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. The issue is that you need to build Gambit before you can build the python interface. Follow the instructions at the top of http://www.gambit-project.org/gambit15/build.html for how to do that.